# Replace href with another href from the same page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

I want to make a button that will have href that is same as another button.

I have one button on my website that not all users see but its almost hidden and hard to reach. This button has specific UR for every user and contains his ID. On another page I want to create a button that will copy the same href from the other button:

Here is an example:

```html
<div class="row exsisting-button button-hard-to-reach">
    <a href="https://doman.com/user/543456/offers" class="your-offers">See my offers</a>
</div>


<div class="row new-button">
    <a href="" class="new-button">Here are you offers</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use querySelector to find element and getAttribute getAttribute to set get href

```js
document.querySelector('.btn-href').setAttribute('href', 
   document.querySelector('.your-offers').getAttribute('href')
);
```

```html
<div class="row exsisting-button button-hard-to-reach">
    <a href="https://doman.com/user/543456/offers" class="your-offers">See my offers</a>
</div>


<div class="row new-button">
    <a href="" class="new-button btn-href">Here are you offers</a>
</div>
```